# Можно ли в одном предложении использовать два и более двоеточия?

Tags: пунктуация

Собственно, весь вопрос в заголовке. Можно ли? Например:

Дело было так: старушка спросила: "так ли это", на что старик ответил: "не совсем".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело было так. Старушка спросила: "всё ли это", на что старик ответил: "не совсем".

Постановка двух двоеточий не запрещается, если грамматика предложения прочитывается ясно. Три двоеточия обычно не ставится, так как в этом случае, с одной стороны, возможно неправильное понимание смысла предложения, а с другой - нарушается традиция письменного оформления текста, который с тремя двоеточиями смотрится не лучшим образом.

Answer (score 2):

Да, все верно. Три двоеточия не ставится. Обычно в таких предложениях, когда в начале идет текст от автора (вводная часть, описание и т.д.), а потом предложение, вводящее прямую речь, то это предложение обычно начинается с ***абзаца.*** 
 Ваше предложение можно оформить так же.

Answer (score 1):

Дело было так. Старушка спросила: "Так ли это?" - на что старик ответил: "Не совсем".